# Knockout.js button only visible on maximum index of observableArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a table where I want the last row to to display a button, but only on the last row. The code below works on showing and hiding the button, but it appears on every row.

How would I go about only displaying it on the last row?

Viewmodel:

```
var loadCustomFileName = function () {
    for (i = 0; i < self.GetCanSeam().length; i++) {
        var obj = {
            appendFileName: parseFileName(i),
            displayFileName: parseDisplayName(i)
            if (i == self.GetCanSeam().length - 1) {
                self.isMax(true);
            }
        };
        self.GetCustomFile.push(obj);            
    }
};
```

View:

```
<div class="csFormField" data-bind="visible: GetCustomFile().length > 0">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>File Name Template</th>
                <th>File Name Append</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind='foreach: GetCustomFile()'>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="cs-label"><label data-bind="text: displayFileName" /></p></td>
                <td><p><input class="cs-input" data-bind="textInput: appendFileName" />
                       <button class="addFormat" data-bind="visible: isMax">+</button></p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: might be a long shot, but did you initialize isMax to false? And actually i think isMax is in parent context

Comment: I did initialize to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your isMax is initialized on parent context. Maybe try this

```
var obj = {
    appendFileName: parseFileName(i),
    displayFileName: parseDisplayName(i)
};
obj.isMax = ko.observable(i==(self.GetCanSeam().length - 1));
self.GetCustomFile.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the `index` of your `forloop`. If it gets to the last element then visible the button.
Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/12/

```
 self.ArrayLength = ko.observable()
 self.ArrayLength(self.GetCustomFile().length);
```

HTML :

```
<button class="addFormat" data-bind="visible: $index() == $parent.ArrayLength() -1">+</button></p></td>
```